# Python iterate through list and count items of a certain value

Tags: python

Hi I have a python problem whereby I have to count which list elements contain the value 2, in a list with various levels of nest. E.g.:

```
my_list = [[2,3,2,2], [[2,1,2,1], [2,1,1]], [1,1,1]]
```

this list can have have up to three levels of nesting but could also be two or only one level deep.

I have piece of code which sort of works:

```
count = 0
for i in my_list:
    if len(i) > 1:
        for x in i:
            if 2 in x:
                count += 1
    elif i == 2:
        count += 1
```

However, apart from being very ugly, this does not take account of the potential to have a list with a single element which is 2. It also doesn't work to get `len()` on a single `int`.

I know list comprehension should be able to take care of this but I am a litle stuck on how to deal with the potential nesting.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the expected output on the example you give?

Comment: Are you doing this to understand how to navigate list structures, or do you just need a count?  There's already an answer using flatten that's solid.  I you want to do this manually, then you'll need recursion.

Comment: so the output would be: count = 3.

Comment: Do you ever need to handle, for example, `[2, [2,3,2,2], [[2,1,2,1], [2,1,1]], [1,1,1]]`, and if so, what result do you need? (4?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use a variant of the `flatten()` generator from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/367273

The original yields every elements from an arbitrarily nested and irregularly shaped structure of iterables. My variant (below) yields the innermost iterables instead of yielding the scalars.

```
from collections import Iterable

def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, Iterable) and any(isinstance(subel, Iterable) for subel in el):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el

my_list = [[2,3,2,2], [[2,1,2,1], [2,1,1]], [1,1,1]]
print(sum(1 for el in flatten(my_list) if 2 in el))
```

For your example it prints `3`.

Comment: Very nice solution... perhaps include the definition of flatten in your answer to make this easier to understand without needing to go to the other answer as well?

Comment: Where does `collections` come from in this case?

Comment: `import collections`. This solution counts *all* the 2's.

Comment: This is fantastic. I tested in a more complex example and it turns up the right solution. I assumed going into this that this would be a very common design pattern. Is it not?

Comment: @DarwinTech: I think Python generators are great, and I think this is a good use case for them.

Comment: Thanks again. Definitely an area of python which deserves more of my attention.

Answer (score 0):

### Update and final answer:

My solution recurses a nested list of lists. If the list contains `2`, the count is set to one. Then the sum of the counts of any sub-lists are added. This approach supports heterogeneous lists where numbers and lists can be mixed at the same level, as in the second usage example below:

```
import collections

def list_count(l):
    count = int(2 in l)
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable):
            count += list_count(el)
    return count
```

Here are a couple of test cases:

```
my_list = [[2,3,2,2], [[2,1,2,1], [2,1,1]], [1,1,1]]
print = list_count(my_list)
# 3 is printed

my_list = [2, [2,3,2,2], [[2,1,2,1], [2,1,1]], [1,1,1]]
print = list_count(my_list)
# 4 is printed
```

@Akavall's answer reminded me this could be collapsed to a one-liner. (But I always get (usually justified) readability complaints on SO when I do this.)

```
def list_count(l):
    return ( int(2 in l) +
        sum([list_count(el) for el in l 
            if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable)]) )
```

### Original Answer (not what original question was looking for)

Update: @NPE updated his answer after expected result was specified. He's current answer works as the original poster desires.

@NPE's (original) answer is close, but you asked:

> count which list elements contain the value 2

Which I read as you needing:

```
my_list = [[2,3,2,2], [[2,1,2,1], [2,1,1]], [1,1,1]]
print(sum([1 for e in [flatten(sl) for sl in ml] if 2 in e]))
```

But he's looking for `3`. My code generates 2 because it iterates across each top level element and counts it if it contains any 2, but that's not what he actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this:

```
small_list = [2]
my_list = [[2,3,2,2], [[2,1,2,1], [2,1,1]], [1,1,1]]
another_list = [[2,3,2,2], [[2,1,2,1], [2,1,1]], [1,1,1], 2]

from collections import Iterable 

def count_lists_w_two(x):
    if isinstance(x, Iterable) == False:
        return 0
    else:
        return (2 in x) + sum(count_lists_w_two(ele) for ele in x)
```

Result:

```
>>> count_lists_w_two(small_list)
1
>>> count_lists_w_two(my_list)
3
>>> count_lists_w_two(another_list)
4
```

Comment: Why not instead of `any(ele == 2 for ele in x)` just use `2 in x`?

Comment: @jimhark, I wasn't even thinking about `2 in x`. Is it better? It is shorter, of course, but I think both are pretty clear. Do you think `2 in x` has an advantage in speed?

Comment: you're writing code to implement a built-in which usually isn't a good idea. A reader has more to read, and in this case may re-read asking, "why not use the built-in"? I fully expect your approach to be slower, but I make it a policy not guess about Python performance. I'll leave the performance testing to you. Please share any results.

Comment: @jimhark, the build-in is about 3 times faster according my rather sloppy test, I guess enough reason for me to edit my code. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't help but test too. After a quick test using `timeit`, it looks like the built in is up to almost 20 times faster when the list is short or the match is early in the list. For longer lists with a match near the end, it drops off to almost 4 times faster.

Comment: Your `is_two_in` is now so simple you might think about calling the build-in `in` directly.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, I also changed the name of my `count_twos` to something more understandable.